# Conditional inline tags in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have certain tags for tracking events in analytics.

```
  <div class="video"
   analytics-event="{{track.event}}"
   analytics-category="{{track.category}}">
   ...
  </div>
```

The thing is that sometimes `track.event` (or `track.category`) is empty and I don't want that empty tag in there. `<div class="video" analytics-event>...<div>`

Is there a way to display them conditionally?

Comment: I still dont get what you want, if track.event is empty and track.category is not empty, do you want to display? <div class="video"
   analytics-category="xxx">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`ng-if`**

```
<div ng-if="track.event" class="video"
   analytics-event="{{track.event}}">
   ...
</div>
```

if it does not present,

```
<div  ng-if="!track.event" class="video"
   analytics-event>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, ok, and what if I have two tags?

Comment: what do you mean by two tags?

Comment: just add a condition ng-if="track.event" && "track.category"

Comment: @JorgeAnzola did it help

Comment: Yes @Sajeetharan, indeed. Thanks. I think that is probably not the best solution, but for my short understanding of Angular, I think is fine.